# Is System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send synchronous?

Tags: smtpclient

Considering that SmtpClient has a SendAsync method which I'm not using, is it safe therefore to assume the StmpClient.Send is synchronous? I'm using it to send an email with  temporary file attachment and want to know whether I can delete the temporary attachment immediately afterwards.

Thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 9):

From the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send.aspx): "Sends an e-mail message to an SMTP server for delivery. These methods block while the message is being transmitted.".

So yes it's synchronous.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the "send" to the smtp server is synchronous, but if you were trying to make sure the message got to its intended destination, you're out of luck.  SmtpClient will wash its hands of the operation as soon as the Smtp server acknowledges receipt.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's synchronous.